# Changing max-height back to zero as transition or animation

Tags: javascript, css

So I have got an animation on an object (`<div>`).

```
@keyframes fade-in-left {
0% {
    max-height: 0px;
}
100% {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

This animation obviously happens when the object is being created. What I need now is an animation or transition that shrinks my object back down to `max-height: 0px;`.

- Giving the property `max-height` an transition and then changing the value of it in js to `0px` does nothing.
- Also creating a reversed animation and then repolacing the original
  object with a clone and this animation does not bring the object down
  to `0px`.

(Please keep in mind that I am not intersted in changing the scale or other transform properties)

Thanks for your suggestions!

More details:

My `<div>` object:

```
    @keyframes fade-in-left {
    0% {
        max-height: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        max-height: 200px;
    }
 }

.law-list .law-item {
    -webkit-transition: max-height .9s linear;
    -moz-transition: max-height .9s linear;
    -ms-transition: max-height .9s linear;
    -o-transition: max-height .9s linear;
    transition: max-height .9s linear;
}

.fade-in {
    -webkit-animation-duration: .9s;
    animation-duration: .9s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade-in-left;
         animation-name: fade-in-left;
}
```

I create my html content in js and the html elements looks like this:

```
<div class='law-item fade-in' id='law_0'>Law Nr.1</div>
<div class='law-item fade-in' id='law_1'>Law Nr.2</div>
```

So when an element is created, the `max-height` animation plays.

When I want to delete an object, I want the situation stated above to occur: a fade out animation and then an deletion.

I handel his in a js function:

```
function removeLaw(id) {
    document.getElementById("law_" + id).style.maxHeight = "0px";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("law_" + id).parentElement.removeChild(document.getElementById("law_" + id));
    }, 900);
}
```

As stated it should fade out to 0 `max-height`. But all it does it stay at the current `max-height` and then after `max-height` get deleted.

Comment: Have a look at the "transitionend" event. You could remove the class of your first transition and initialize another transition right after your first one finished.

Comment: What are the conditions for transitioning back to `max-height: 0`?

Comment: @wlh Well if I assignt zero to style.maxHeight in js, no transition happens. It does not even shrink down to zero without transition, it just stays unchanged.

Comment: Ok. We'll need more code to be able to help you here. Give us the `div`, the `css` for that div, in addition to `keyframes` above, and the `js` you are using to solve your problem. We can't help you without more information. Ultimately, what user or logical events are you using to trigger the expansion and the shrinking?

Comment: @wlh Okay, one second.

Comment: @wlh I have added the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always more than one way to do something. Since you are using an animation to set the height, it is best to use an animation to remove the height as well. Think of the animation ending at `100%`. At this point, your `max-height` is set. Even though you have a transition set on the element, the animation is preventing the transition from firing as it should. The animation event is still firing even though it is at 100%. You could set an event listener on the `animationend` event from the beginning and pause the animation. I haven't tried this, but it may work.

What I found in your case is to create a `fade-out` class and a `fade-out` animation. I removed all references to `transition` from your css since I used animations. I suppose you could go the other way and use only transitions instead of animations, but mixing them is the problem you have been having.

I created a basic click event listener on each `law-item` and changed the class on the item prior to removing when the new animation ended.

```js
function removeLaw(id) {
   var el = document.getElementById(id);
   el.classList.remove('fade-in');
   el.classList.add('fade-out');
   el.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
    el.remove();
   })
}

var lawItems = document.querySelectorAll('.law-item');

lawItems.forEach(function(lawItem){
  this.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    removeLaw(e.target.id)
  })
})
```

```css
@keyframes fade-in-left {
    0% {
        max-height: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        max-height: 200px;
    }
 }
 
 @keyframes fade-out-left {
    0% {
        max-height: 200px;
    }
    100% {
        max-height: 0px;
    }
 }

.law-list .law-item {
    height: 200px;

}

.fade-in {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 900ms;
    animation-duration: 900ms;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade-in-left;
         animation-name: fade-in-left;
}

.fade-out {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 900ms;
    animation-duration: 900ms;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade-out-left;
         animation-name: fade-out-left;
}
```

```html
<div class='law-list'>

  <div class='law-item fade-in' id='law_0'>Law Nr.1</div>
  <div class='law-item fade-in' id='law_1'>Law Nr.2</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, it works well! One question: What should I do, if the .law-item class contains a padding? Then the delete-animation will not be completed as it is now.

Comment: Padding and margin would affect the visuals. You can either animate those as well, or before changing the classes, change the style of the particular `law-item` to some visual form that removes `top` and `bottom` padding. This may cause jankiness in the overall visuals though, so animating them may be the best solution.